# solution for script error with only access runtime

Tags: windows, vbscript, runtime, ms-access-2007, activex

I have a pc with only access 2007 runtime installed, NO complete access sw.
I use .vbs script for run a module, like this:

```
dim accessApp
set accessApp = createObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("C:\Temp\test.accdb")
accessApp.Run "MailOrder"
accessApp.Quit
set accessApp = nothing
```

but reply me error **800A01AD ActiveX component cannot create object: 'Access.Application'**
Error of run-time of Microsoft VBScipt

I've tried also with cscript.exe but nothing, same error.
I need to use on pc with only access runtime, without normal access.
I have no idea to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening it directly using `Shell`.

Let it execute a *macro*, here `RunMailOrder`, that executes your function `MailOrder`:

```vb
Dim Shell

Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "C:\Temp\test.accdb /x RunMailOrder"

Set Shell = Nothing
```

[Command-line switches for Microsoft Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#Category=Access?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your shell run but how I can run my module named "MailOrder" by that? and at the end close my db? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: See extended answer, please.

Comment: Thanks, but now how can execute a module by a macro?

Comment: Create new macro, set it to run the function, save the macro. You cannot execute a module.